# Error in AES Encryption using C++

Tags: c++, encryption, aes

I have done [Encryption of a File using C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM` as `CALG_RC4`. The code is working fine. When I changed the `ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM` to `CALG_AES_256` it fails.

```
if(CryptAcquireContext(
    &hCryptProv, 
    NULL, 
    MS_ENHANCED_PROV, 
    PROV_RSA_FULL, 
    CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
```

and

```
   if(!CryptDeriveKey(
          hCryptProv, 
          ENCRYPT_ALGORITHM, 
          hHash, 
          KEYLENGTH, 
          &hKey))
```

fails with the error no. `0x80090016` and `0x8009000f`

I want to perform AES 256 Encryption and also want to include the SHA-512 hashing along with the encryption `CALG_SHA_512`. What are the things I need to modify?

Note: I don't want to use any 3rd Party API's for performing this operation.

Comment: try replacing `CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT` to `CRYPT_NEWKEYSET` in the first call (that was recommended [here](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/238187)). In the second call, I think the error means "object already exists", and you must somehow use `CRYPT_DELETEKEYSET` to delete it.